# Does rails have an opposite of `parameterize` for strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I used `parameterize` method. I want to de-parameterize it. Is there a method to do the opposite of `parameterize`?

Comment: Nope - because `parametrize` method removes some information about original string.

Comment: Rails has a titleize which will capitalize the first letter and remove the dashes removes. "my-awesome-pizza".titleize => "My Awesome Pizza"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, there is not. `parameterize` is a lossy conversion, you can't convert it back.

Here's an example. When you convert

```
My Awesome Pizza
```

into

```
my-awesome-pizza
```

you have no idea if the original string was

```
My Awesome Pizza
MY AWESOME PIZZA
```

etc. This is a simple example. However, as you can see from the [source code](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-parameterize), certain characters are stripped or converted into a separator (e.g. commas) and you will not be able to recover them.

If you just want an approximate conversion, then simply convert the dashes into spaces, trim multiple spaces and apply an appropriate case conversion.

Answer (score 15):

In Rails there is `titleize` ([source](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/titleize)):

```
"this-is-my-parameterized-string".titleize
=> "This Is My Parameterized String"
```

```
"hello-world foo bar".titleize
=> "Hello World Foo Bar"
```

As mentioned above, this isn't going to revert the string to its pre-parameterized form, but if that's not a concern, this might help!

Answer (score 9):

I'm with Simone on this one but you can always go with

```
def deparametrize(str)
  str.split("-").join(" ").humanize
end
```

:)

Comment: Check out `tr`. If str = "stop-the-bad-guy" then `str.tr("-", " ").humanize` will return "Stop the bad-guy"